# Updating a single record Via ID = ID

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've ran into a wall at the moment, This code brings up a table with a button on the end of each record. Once pressed this then does a function to UPDATE the Health record by -5.

This works great for the job but it effects all rows, I've tried to get it to only touched one record via the ID but no luck! if you can help that would be great!

the php

```
$sql="SELECT `id` , `FirstName` , `Health` FROM ajax_demo WHERE `id` = `id` LIMIT 0 , 30";
$result = mysql_query($sql);


if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
counterminus();
}
  function  counterminus()
{
$cmeter = $cmeter - 1;

$id = $_POST["id"];
$FirstName = $_POST["FirstName"];

mysql_query("UPDATE ajax_demo SET `Health` = `Health` - `Damage` WHERE id = {$id}");
Header("location:oo_test.php");
}
```

This is the php / form

```
<?php 
echo 
"<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>health</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $cell) {
        echo "\n<td>$cell</td>";
}
echo '<td><form id="theForm" action="" method="POST" >
<input type="submit" name="submit"  id="submit" value="Attack" />
<input type="hidden" name="'.$row[1].'" /></form></td></tr>';
 echo "\n\n";
 }?>
```

Comment: "this is the form" is not a form but PHP code. The real form is rendered in the browser

Answer (score 0):

This is vunerable to attack through the `$_POST['id']` variable. Use `mysql_real_escape_string`, or better, prepared queries through PDO or MySQLi, anyway this is orthogonal to the issue you are having, it's just a good idea to be aware of it.

You're never actually submitting a HTML form field with the name `id`. In addition, in your HTML, `$row` will be `NULL` outside of your while loop, so will be undefined in the first place. This will mean that the name of your hidden field will be blank, and that your SQL is saying `UPDATE WHERE id=`, which is invalid and will cause an error.

To fix, you need to submit a form field with the name "id" such that `$_POST['id']` actually contains a value.

Comment: Could you possibly give me an example of using the mysql_real_escape_string? I'll try adding in a textfield or similar to give me a value to work with.

Answer (score -1):

Why did you write {id} instead of $id ?

Plus your code is totally unsafe and could be easily altered and hacked.

You should try PDO instead of mysql_query which is also depreciated.
http://php.net/PDO

Comment: `{$id}` is valid PHP in string interpolation, and is useful for the case where you use underscores. `"foo_$bar_baz"` has a different meaning to `"foo_{$bar}_baz"`.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't knew. I'll dig into it when i'll have more time. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing - have a look at the complex/curly syntax. Also, my example might be the other way around and have `_baz` inside the braces, I can't remember where string interpolation in PHP stops...

Comment: Right, Looks like I need to rewrite the code then, thanks for the feedback. Would you know of any good PDO tutorials before I go digging?